# Ubuntu freezes on first boot on samsumg series 9

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, samsung

I have just wiped windows 8 from my samsumg series 9 by installing Ubuntu 12 64 bit over it through usb.

I have **fast bios mode** disabled and os mode selection set to csm os and the boot usb removed from the laptop after installation.

When reboot from hard disk, I have 4 choices (grub version 1.99-21ubuntu3.9)

1. ubuntu, with linux 3.5.0-23-generic
2. ubuntu, with linux 3.5.0-23-generic (recovery mode)
3. memory test (memtest86+)
4. memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)

I picked 1 and screen turned black with a cursor flashing. note that I am not having a dual boot machine. I am stuck at this screen, please somebody help, I really don't want to revert back to windows.

Answer (score 0):

you need to restart your X-server. That in most cases solves this kind of problems. Check wether is rightly installed